# I tried to create a List array from errors in flutter but I run into an error each time i run the code

Tags: arrays, list, flutter

It's clear to me that the error is from

> Text(errors[0])

because when change the the code to

> Text('Demo Error')

it runs perfect.
The error generated is

> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

This is the entire file.
{would you just let me post this file and stop tell me its mostly code. I know its mostly code}

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:fund_me_zuri/components/login_button.dart';
import 'package:fund_me_zuri/size_config.dart';

import '../../../constants.dart';

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const Body({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/fundMeLogo.svg'),
            SizedBox(
              height: getProportionateScreenHeight(40),
            ),
            DonorSignin(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DonorSignin extends StatefulWidget {
  const DonorSignin({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DonorSigninState createState() => _DonorSigninState();
}

class _DonorSigninState extends State<DonorSignin> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final List<String> errors = ["Demo Error",];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          buildEmailFormField(),
          SizedBox(
            height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20),
          ),
          buildPasswordFormField(),
          SizedBox(
            height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/Error.svg',
              ),
              Text(errors[0]),
            ],
          ),
          LoginButton(
            text: 'Log In',
            press: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildPasswordFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Password',
        hintText: 'Enter your password',
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: kPrimaryColor),
          gapPadding: 10,
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: kPrimaryColor),
          gapPadding: 10,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildEmailFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty){
          setState(() {
            errors.add('Please enter your email');
          });
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Email',
        hintText: 'Enter your Email',
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: kPrimaryColor),
          gapPadding: 10,
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: kPrimaryColor),
          gapPadding: 10,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire file ? I try with the example that you give and it's work fine in my computer.

Comment: I tested and works fine too.

Comment: Is this fine. ?